# jquery: hide a popup on mouseleave event of trigger or popup

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I have a popup menu appearing onclick event of an element on my page like this...

```
$('.triggerDiv').click(function() {
    var pos = $(this).offset();
    $('#popupDiv').css({
            "left": (pos.left + this.width()) + "px",
            "top": pos.top + "px"
        }).slideDown();
});
```

I also have a mouseleave event attached to the popup to hide it on mouseleave.

```
$('#popupDiv').mouseleave(function() {
    $('#popupDiv').slideUp();
});
```

What I want to do is hide the popup if the mouse leaves the trigger as well. Simple solution would be -

```
$('.triggerDiv').mouseleave(function() {
    $('#popupDiv').slideUp();
});
```

But the problem is that I have multiple trigger elements on the page that all display the same popup onclick. In this case how can I correctly handle the mouseleave event to hide/show the popup?

Comment: You only have 1 element with the id "popupDiv", how can multiple elements trigger it to be shown?

Comment: @iWantSimpleLife - in the trigger element click event I also use absolute positioning to display the popup menu to the right of trigger.

Comment: @ShiVik Your code looks very reasonable.  Are you having any problems with it?  The only thing I'd change is instead of selecting for `"#popupDiv"` and `".triggerDiv"` separately, I'd select for both types of elements at the same time using `"#popupDiv, .triggerDiv"`.

Comment: @Xavi - one problem is that when the mouseleave event of trigger occurs, the popup hides. I want to hide the popup when mouse leaves both trigger and popup, not just one of them.

Comment: @ShiVik I see.  I'll post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that the popup only closes when use's mouse has left both the popup and the trigger-div, try this code:

```
var closeTimer;

$("#popupDiv, .triggerDiv")
    .mouseleave(function() {
        closeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            $('#popupDiv').slideUp();
        }, 300);
    })
    .mouseenter(function() {
        if(closeTimer) { closeTimer = clearTimeout(closeTimer); }
    });
```

The code above uses the [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) function to wait 300 milliseconds before closing the popup.  This gives the user enough time to move their mouse from the trigger-div to the popup and vise versa.  Note that when the user's mouse enters the popup, the code prevents the popup from closing by using `clearTimeout` to cancel the `closeTimer`.  In my experience this makes popups and hover menus much easier to use.

Also, if there are large number of `.triggerDiv`s, I'd consider using [live events](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Answer (score 0):

Use a JQuery `$(this)` reference in the function body:

```
$('.triggerDiv').mouseleave(function() { 
    $(this).slideUp(); 
});
```

Comment: I want to hide(slideup) the popup menu not the trigger element itself.